# Is there a way to search for those questions that have only negative votes?

Tags: support, search

I would like to search for questions with less than 0 votes (that is, only negative votes). There is a way to search for 0 or more, but not 0 or less?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will search for question with a score of 0 or less:

```
score:..0 is:question
```

Answer (score 4):

[Meta question with score less than zero](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=score:..-1%20is:question)

**Steps to produce:**

search:

```
score:..-1 is:question
```

and sort by vote.